# How do I configure testing in Gradle for an Eclipse web application using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, testing, web-applications, gradle

I am trying to integrate Gradle to an eclipse web application project that uses the spring framework.
So far the build.gradle file seems to mostly work. I can start the application in Eclipse, the application gets deployed to the Tomcat container and I can interact with the web application in a browser.  The war file appears to work as well.

The problem is with testing.  When I run gradle test, most tests fail. Yet, if I run them from JUnit in Eclipse, the tests pass. Assuming it is possible, what should I modify in the build.gradle file so that testing works.  At this time, (major) changes to the project code (ex, changing structure) is not desirable.

See the relevant parts below,

The Eclipse project structure (http://svn.constellio.com/constellio/trunk/?p=2033)

```
Eclipse project root
  source/java/
  source/java/constellio.xml (xml beans configuration file)
  source/java/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
  source/javaspring-util-2.0.xsd
  source/javatests/
  WebContent/
  WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml (xml servlet configuration file)
  WebContent/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml (other beans configuration file)
  WebContent/WEB-INF/locallibs (Libraries that are not from a Maven repository)
  build.gradle
```

The build.gradle (http://svn.constellio.com/constellio/trunk/build.gradle?p=2033)

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "eclipse-wtp"

project.webAppDirName = 'WebContent'

repositories{
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
            url "http://maven.restlet.org"
    }
}

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs file("source/java")
sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs file("source/javatests")

dependencies{
  // Omitted as it seems to work in Eclipse, svn link for more details
  ... 
}

// Small subset of tests generating errors with gradle test
test {
  include "com/doculibre/constellio/entities/skos/**"
}
```

So far I have tried using various options in Gradle, even

```
sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs fileTree("source") + fileTree("WebContent")
sourceSets.test.resources.srcDirs fileTree("source") + fileTree("WebContent")
```

which I assume makes everything accessible on the classpath but even then I get errors such as

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.gradle.internal.SystemProperties
```

or

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [constellio.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [constellio.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Let me know if you have any ideas,

Thanks,

**Update**

Guava was in the dependencies and according to GRADLE-2962 in the Gradle forum it may cause problems. I removed it and I am getting more sensible error messages now.